# Message "file too large for recycle bin" on any file on external HDD Win 10

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, ntfs

On my external only-files (no Windows) NTFS 2TB HDD Win 10 raises a "file too large for recycle bin" message on any file I delete.
I formatted the HDD with the onboard Windows partition tool and the HDD is 20% full.
How can I fix this and send files to the recycle bin instead of deleting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Windows *Explorer*, right-click on the *Recycle Bin*. Select *Properties*. Be sure that the option *Don't move files to the Recycle Bin...* is **not** checked and verify that there is enough space in *Custom size:* to delete files, without taking up excessive room on the disk.

[image: Recycle Bin Properties]

Let me know if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Thank you! This resolves my issue, somehow the custom size was set extremely low...

Comment: Also, **Pay attention to partitions** for which you increase the size.