# Windows: Make space in Recycle Bin by removing existing old stuff, instead of "Too big too delete"?

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

When a file or folder is too big for recycle bin, Windows offers *File too big for Bin, permanently delete?*.

The Bin may contain old stuff that is taking space and could be deleted to make room for the new one. But instead, Windows wants to permanently delete the new stuff while not touching what's in the Bin already.

How can we make it delete old stuff in Bin to make room for the latest deletions?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Message "file too large for recycle bin" on any file on external HDD Win 10](https://superuser.com/questions/994767/message-file-too-large-for-recycle-bin-on-any-file-on-external-hdd-win-10)

Comment: You should never use the Recycle bin as a storage folder. Review it, restore anything you need, and ten empty.  Empty it at least weekly